# abas-ERP: place cursor at second appearance of field

Tags: erp, abas

It sometimes happens that a field - say `xfield` - appears twice in a mask (in different tabs). Is there a way to place the cursor programmatically in the **second** appearance of the field?

The command `.cursor xfield` always jumps to the first appearance and I didn't find anything in the documentation that points towards the possibility of doing that.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way for doing that. The cursor jumps always to the first occurance. Sometimes I use a workaround and place the cursor into another field within the same register to force a register switch.